# Typescript error when curried defition is after the uncurried definition

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I am receiving error: `Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)` when I place uncurried definition of method above the curried definition.

Failing `dtslint` test:

```
function match(regExpression: RegExp, str: string): string[]; 
function match(regExpression: RegExp): (str: string) => string[]; 

function throttle<T, U>(fn: (input: T) => U, ms: number): (input: T) => U;
function throttle<T, Q, U>(
  fn: (input1: T, input2: Q) => U, ms: number
): (input1: T, input2: Q) => U;

it('match', () => {
    const fn = throttle(match, 1000)
    fn(/foo/,'foo bar')  // line of error
})
```

If I move the curried `match` definition above the uncurried definition, then the error disappears.

My question is should I indeed place uncurried version after the curried version, or there is error in `throttle` definition?

---

The context of the question is writing Typescript definitions for a library similar to `ramda`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript checks overloaded signatures (which are internally intersection types) in top to bottom order. When `throttle` chooses which signature to use to infer generic parameters (almost same as conditional types), it always selects last signature.

Closely related feature of TS type system is described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496):

> When inferring from a type with multiple call signatures (such as the type of an overloaded function), inferences are made from the last signature (which, presumably, is the most permissive catch-all case). It is not possible to perform overload resolution based on a list of argument types (this would require us to support typeof for arbitrary expressions, as suggested in #6606, or something similar).

Comment: much appreciated